# Regular Expression validating with "at"

Tags: java, regex

I know how to validate an email adress using regular expression, when the mail has the structure "blabla@foo.com"
The valid regular expression looks like this:

```
([\w\-]([\.\w])+[\w]+@([\w\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})
```

But at my university, my professors do have websites in which their email adresses look like this: `prof[at]foo.bla`

What is the correct regular expression for this kind of emails? Changing `@` to `[at]` didn't work.

Is there any tutorial for this kind of problems? Can you please recommend something?

Comment: `(\w+(?:@|\[at\])([\w-]+.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})`  but i why `-+` you example doesn't have any `-`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh thank you very much.

Comment: Beware that `{2,4}`.  Many top-level domains have more than four characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use optional capture here - the `|` character in a group works as a logical `or`, so:

```
(\w-+[\w]+(@|\[at\])([\w-]+.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})
```

Should do the trick. You can set it as non-capturing group `(?:@|\[at\])` if you're not interested in it. Also, note that the square brackets are escaped - you need to escape them if you want to treat them as literal characters instead of character group indicators.

**UPDATE**

Since you didn't specify the language you're using in the original question, here's what I'd suggest you to use:

```
Pattern emailRe = Pattern.compile("(\\w[\\w.+\\-]+?(?:@|\\[at\\])[\\w\\-]+\\.[\\w\\-.]+)");
```

instead as a much more solid pattern. Then you can re-use it to match email(s) in your strings as many times as you like, for example: `emailRe.match(your_string)`...

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice explaination. Can accept your answer in 7 minutes, unfortunately :)

Comment: Eclipse is showing an error when using your expression.
"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Comment: @Blnpwr I just updated your pattern which leaves a lot to be desired, you should consider using `(\w[\w.+\-]*?(?:@|\[at\])[\w\-]+\.[\w\-.]+)` instead for much better email match.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but Eclipse still throws the same error as above, using Java.

Comment: You didn't specify the language you're using... Double escape everything if writing it as a string literal (replace all \  with \\\)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`(\w[-.\w]+(?:@|\[at\])[\w-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})`](https://regex101.com/r/0M8R7z/4)

just add an non-capturing group with or anchor `|` to match either `@` or `\[at\]` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441092/regular-expression-validating-with-at/44441208#comment75879958_44441092)

Note : you need not to escape `-` and `.` inside `[]`

Answer (score 1):

`[` and `]`] have special meaning in regular expressions, so you have to escape them to match literally. So replace `@` with `\[at\]` in your regexp.

```
([\w\-]([\.\w])+[\w]+\[at\]([\w\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})
```

You can find a regular expression tutorial at [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expression.info).

Comment: If I do so, Eclipse throws an error like this: "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Comment: What programming language are you using? You may need to double the backslashes to get them through the string literal representation. If the language has "raw strings" you should use that.

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes by doubling them.

Comment: You should have seen this in any examples of using regular expressions in Java.